# jQuery UI Datepicker month and year combo not working in jQuery BlockUI (Popup)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

When i open jQuery UI datepicker in BlockUI (popup) and try to change month and year, dropdown does not open. It's working fine in popup but out side of datepicker.

#### HTML:

```
<div class="popup">
    Date Picker<input type="text" class="datepicker" />
</div>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $.blockUI({
        message:$('.popup'),
        focusInput: false,
        onBlock:function(){}
    });

    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        yearRange: 'c-10:c+3',
        showButtonPanel: false            
    }); 
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FhHK/204/)**

Comment: Yes you're right. And now? I don't know what is your question...

Comment: Please check above jsFiddle link. When i open jQuery UI date picker in blockUI and wan't to change month and year combo but it's not working.

Comment: The blockUI plugin block all input on the screen so it makes sense if you can't "click" on the drop downs or on usual HTML input elements. Can you use a jQuery UI dialog with modal option instead?

Comment: Dropdown working fine in popup but outside of Datepicker. You can check here: http://jsfiddle.net/4FhHK/209/

Comment: @Clive: Sorry for that. I have added description.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because [jquery blockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/) is catching your click event, have a look at its `handler()` function :

```
// event handler to suppress keyboard/mouse events when blocking
function handler(e) {
    // allow tab navigation (conditionally)
    [...]
    var opts = e.data;
    // allow events within the message content
    if ($(e.target).parents('div.' + opts.blockMsgClass).length > 0)
        return true;

    // allow events for content that is not being blocked
        return $(e.target).parents().children().filter('div.blockUI').length == 0;
};
```

So your click event will be propagated ONLY :

- if the clicked element ancestor's is a `div` with css class `blockMsg` (or your own class if you have changed the default `blockMsgClass` option value)
- or if your clicked element ancestor's children are not div with `.blockUI` css class

The problem is that the jquery-ui datepicker div (`div#ui-datepicker-div`) is automatically appended outside your `div.popup` so it is not fulfilling any of these requirements.

So a quick fix will be to add the css class `blockMsg` to the datpicker div (which is an ancestor of the clicked `select` element) as in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FhHK/216/).

Another solution would be to append the datepicker div to the popup div once it has been generated but you will have positionning problem when you will open the datepicker.

Comment: Great catch, beat me for a second +1 :-)

Comment: Same issue for me while using jQuery datepicker with bootstrap modal. @яden Any clues???